# Updating AudioKit for Swift 5 Using Precompiled Framework

Tags: ios, audiokit

I have a few apps where I implemented AudioKit by importing the precompiled frameworks provided from the website, and not CocoaPods.  However, after updating to Swift 5 it seems like (currently) only the GitHub files are updated.

The Git download doesn't seem to have any "AudioKit.framework" files, and when I try and pre-compile my own and import CoreAudioKit using the provided instructions my project is getting errors. I don't think Xcode is recognizing the AudioKit items ("Use of unresolved identifier 'AKDuration'"...etc).

Is there another location to download v4.7 precompiled files?  Or am I missing a step when making my own?

I'm a huge fan of AudioKit and look forward to getting it back up and running in my projects!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that universal frameworks containing Swift 5 code are no longer supported by Xcode 10.2. This causes these kinds of unexpected errors when building an app for a device and using pre-compiled universal frameworks from our pod, or by using our build scripts.

Specifically, we're now going to have to ship separate binaries for device and simulator platforms.

We're in the process of revamping the way the frameworks are built and distributed to address these issues, hopefully v4.7.1 will address it. In the meantime, you should at least be able to compile for the simulators with the provided package, so I'd be curious to know if that is not working for you.